# Cannot use keras model.predict after creating sequential model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I create and save a Keras sequential model:

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Input(shape=(20)))
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu')) function is used for the nuerons
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(test_data_x, test_data_y, epochs=150, batch_size=8)
    model.save('TestNN.h5')
```

I then load and try to predict:

```
    loaded_model = keras.models.load_model('TestNN.h5')
    pred = loaded_model.predict(test_data)
```

And i get this error:

```
    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential' (type Sequential).
    Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full    shape received: (None,)

    Call arguments received by layer 'sequential' (type Sequential):
        • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=float32)
        • training=False
        • mask=None
```

I am new to the Keras world but i thought this sequential model was pretty straight forward. I am not quite sure what I'm doing wrong, any help is much appreciated.

PS. I am using Keras v2.12.0

I had hoped to build a simple sequential model for binary classification, however i am unable to use Keras predict() function.

Comment: If your test data is a single sample, it must have shape (1, 20).

Comment: What is the `shape` of your `test_data_x` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your input shape should be a tuple denoting the shape of an individual sample. What shape is your input data?

Let's say it is an RGB image of shape 224x224x3 then your code should be updated as such:

```
Input(shape=(224,224,3))
```

where the batch size will be interpreted from the fit function

Comment: Hey mate sorry for the late reply, been a bit caught up. So just training the model with a set of numbers with a length of 20. Example: (1,2,3,4,5,6,7...) etc. So does that mean that my input shape would be: Input(shape=(1, 20)) ? Also this error only occurs when i attempt to reload the model and continue training. I apologize if my formatting is a bit off. I'm new stack overflow. Many thanks, Timothy